# Alternatives to using pack_into() when manipulating a list of bytes?

Tags: python, binary, struct

I'm reading in a binary file into a list and parsing the binary data. I'm using unpack() to extract certain parts of the data as primitive data types, and I want to edit that data and insert it back into the original list of bytes. Using [pack_into()](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) would make it easy, except that I'm using Python 2.4, and pack_into() wasn't introduced until 2.5

Does anyone know of a good way to go about serializing the data this way so that I can accomplish essentially the same functionality as pack_into()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`bitstring`](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) module? It's designed to make the construction, parsing and modification of binary data easier than using the `struct` and `array` modules directly.

It's especially made for working at the bit level, but will work with bytes just as well. It will also work with Python 2.4.

```
from bitstring import BitString
s = BitString(filename='somefile')

# replace byte range with new values
# The step of '8' signifies byte rather than bit indicies.
s[10:15:8] = '0x001122'

# Search and replace byte value with two bytes
s.replace('0xcc', '0xddee', bytealigned=True)

# Different interpretations of the data are available through properties
if s[5:7:8].int > 1000:
    s[5:7:8] = 1000

# Use the bytes property to get back to a Python string
open('newfile', 'wb').write(s.bytes)
```

The underlying data stored in the `BitString` is just an `array` object, but with a comprehensive set of functions and special methods to make it simple to modify and interpret.

Comment: This is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean editing data in a buffer object?  Documentation on manipulating those at all from Python directly is fairly scarce.

If you just want to edit bytes in a string, it's simple enough, though; struct.pack_into is new to 2.5, but struct.pack isn't:

```
import struct
s = open("file").read()
ofs = 1024
fmt = "Ih"
size = struct.calcsize(fmt)

before, data, after = s[0:ofs], s[ofs:ofs+size], s[ofs+size:]
values = list(struct.unpack(fmt, data))
values[0] += 5
values[1] /= 2
data = struct.pack(fmt, *values)
s = "".join([before, data, after])
```